# Vibration of a string at a frquency other than the resonance frequency

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, harmonic-oscillator, resonance

We know that if we attach an oscillator/vibrator to a string with either the natural frequency or one of its harmonics, it exhibits resonance and a pure standing wave is produced.

But here, i am searching for a general equation and nature of the wave produced by an oscillator at any general frequency f other than the natural frequency?

Moreover, the amplitude of the wave as a function of time (in the absence of any external forces).

Comment: You could read on *forced oscillations*, even the simplest case with equation: $\ddot{x} + \gamma\dot{x}+\omega_0^2x=f(t)$ where the driving force is $f(t)=f_0\cos(\omega t)$ with $\omega\neq\omega_0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at the [Driven Harmonic oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator). The differential equation looks like
$$m\ddot{x}+b\dot{x}+kx=F_0\cos\omega t$$
The driven  response look like
$$x(t)=X_0\cos(\omega t+\phi)$$
where $$X_0=\frac{F_0}{m}\frac{1}{[(\omega_0^2-\omega^2)^2+(\omega \gamma )^2]^{1/2}}$$
$$\phi=\arctan\left(\frac{\gamma \omega}{\omega_0^2-\omega^2}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you sir for the answer...
but the point is i am not able to form the wave equation...
The equation you are giving is probably for a single particle forced oscillation